Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sClass') while using datatables
In Index.cshtml: I try to show list of products by using datatables features by using the id="tabledata" on table html tag
@model List<Product>

<div class="card shadow border-0 my-4">
   <div class="card-header bg-secondary bg-gradient ml-0 py-3">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-12 text-center">
            <h2 class="text-white py-0">Product List</h2>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="card-body p-4">
      <div class="row pb-3">
         <div class="col-6">
         </div>
         <div class="col-6 text-end">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-controller="Product" asp-action="Upsert">
            <i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i> Create New Product
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <table id="tableData" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width: 100%">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>
                  Title
               </th>
               <th>
                  ISBN
               </th>
               <th>
                  Author
               </th>
               <th>
                  Price
               </th>
               <th>
                  Category
               </th>
               <th></th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/js/product.js"></script>
}


In product.js: where I define the loadDataTable() function and dataTable variable
$(document).ready(function () {
    loadDataTable();
});

function loadDataTable() {

    dataTable = $('#tableData').DataTable({
        "ajax": { url: '/admin/product/getall' },
        "columns": [
            { data: 'title', "width": "15%" },
            { data: 'isbn', "width": "15%" },
            { data: 'listPrice', "width": "15%" },
            { data: 'author', "width": "15%" },
            { data: 'category.name', "width": "15%" }
        ]
    });
}


Showing Error:
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sClass')
    at et (dataTables.min.js:4:14349)
    at At (dataTables.min.js:4:29734)
    at wt (dataTables.min.js:4:22944)
    at Mt (dataTables.min.js:4:34015)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (dataTables.min.js:4:7044)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2:3003)
    at S.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2:1481)
    at S.fn.init.V [as dataTable] (dataTables.min.js:4:1327)
    at H.fn.DataTable (dataTables.min.js:4:93325)
    at loadDataTable (product.js:13:33)


How to solve this error?


I try to fetch the data from the api call to show the data by using the datatables features but it is showing me the errors

You seem to specify 5 columns in your JavaScript, but there are 6 in your HTML (there is an empty <th></th> at the end). Make sure the number of columns in your JS en HTML match.

This question is similar to: DataTables: Cannot read property style of undefined. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks actually, I tried to add edit and delete option on that  part

what does this have to do with C#?


jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of
undefined (reading 'sClass')

This issue happens when you have more/less columns in your table in the html file than in the js file, where you load the data.
You could remove the extra column here:
<table id="tableData" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width: 100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Title
            </th>
            <th>
                ISBN
            </th>
            <th>
                Author
            </th>
            <th>
                Price
            </th>
            <th>
                Category
            </th>
            @* <th></th> *@  <!--remove the extra  column-->
        </tr> 
    </thead>
</table>

Besides, Your code actually can work fine if I use old version of Datatable.js e.g version 1.10.20.
